# Recurence relation of recursive call inside another

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm trying to analyze the cost of this code:

```c
static int funct1(int x) {
     if (x<=1) return x;
     return funct1(funct1(x/2)) + 1;
}
```

How i could resolve the recurrence relation `T(n)=T(T(n/2))+1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is not correct. `T(n) = T(f(n/2)) + T(n/2) + 1` (You've missed `T(n/2)` but the program should compute `T(n/2)` first and then run `T(f(n/2))`). and it is not `T(T(n/2))`.

Now try to consider `f(n)` as a value of the function `funct1`.
Suppose `n = 2^k`, `f(2^k) = f(f(2^{k-1})) + 1 = f(f(2^{k-2}) + 1) + 1 = ... = f(f(f(...f(1) + 1..)+1)+1) + 1`. `f(1) = 1`, `f(2) = 2`, `f(3) = 2`, `f(4) = 3`, `f(8) = f(f(4)) + 1 = f(3) + 1 = 3`, `f(16) = f(f(8)) + 1 = f(3) + 1 = 3`, and `f(32) = f(f(16)) + 1 = f(3) + 1 = 3`. As you can see it repeats for all values `2^k`, and `f(2^k) = 3`.

Therefore, `T(n) = T(3) + T(n/2) + 1 = O(log n)`.